# Avoid repeated load of file in function

Tags: python, python-3.x, function, fasta

I am trying to write a file with functions to take a fasta file and (i) give an overview of the file, (ii) draw a histogram for length distribution of sequences. I successfully wrote the following code that works:

```
from Bio import SeqIO
from prettytable import PrettyTable
import pylab
import numpy as np
import sys
%matplotlib inline

def fasta_outlook(fasta_file):
    '''Summarize the fasta file with #ofseq, length(min,max). Takes filename as string'''
   => sizes = [len(rec) for rec in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file,"fasta")]
    table = PrettyTable(['Parameter', 'Stats'])
    table.add_row(['No. of Sequences', len(sizes)])
    table.add_row(['Shortest seq.length', min(sizes)])
    table.add_row(['Longest Seq.length', max(sizes)])
    print(table)

def fasta_burst(fasta_file):
    '''Reports the length of each fasta sequence in the file. Takes filename as string'''
    my_file = open("Seq_length.tab","w")
   => for rec in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file,"fasta"):
        my_file.write(rec.id+'\t'+str(len(rec))+'\n')
    print("Length report written in Seq_length.tab")

def fasta_lendist(fasta_file):
    '''plot the distribution of sequence length as histogram. Takes filename as string'''
   => sizes = [len(rec) for rec in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file,"fasta")]
    count,bins,_ = pylab.hist(sizes, bins=100, log=True, histtype='step',color='red')
    pylab.title("%i seq with len: %i to %i bp (range)\nBin Max: %i seq around %i bp"%(len(sizes),min(sizes),max(sizes),count.max(),bins[np.argmax(count)]))
    pylab.xlabel("Sequence length (bp)")
    pylab.ylabel("Log Count")
    pylab.savefig("Sequence_length_distribution_plot.png")
    print("Plot saved as Sequence_length_distribution_plot.png")

fasta = 'filename.fa'
fasta_outlook(fasta)
fasta_lendist(fasta)
```

The problem here is, in all the functions I load the file (=>) repeatedly. Is it possible to load file only once globally and use the object in subsequent functions? Does the arg to a  function take an object instead of filename(string)?

Comment: Write a function to parse out the info you want once, then just pass it around to all the functions.

Comment: Maybe you can add all this to a class and import the file in your __init__ then instantiate once and call where every you want?

Comment: You can load your file in memory to avoid reading it from disk repeatedly... but the you need to have all that memory available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read all the records in once and then pass them to your functions. This may be a very bad idea if your FASTA file is very large. At the bottom of your script:

```
fasta = 'filename.fa'
records = [record for record in SeqIO.parse(fasta,"fasta")]
fasta_outlook(records)
fasta_lendist(records
```

One of your functions would now look like this:

```
def fasta_outlook(fasta_records):
    sizes = [len(rec) for rec in fasta_records]
    table = PrettyTable(['Parameter', 'Stats'])
    table.add_row(['No. of Sequences', len(sizes)])
    table.add_row(['Shortest seq.length', min(sizes)])
    table.add_row(['Longest Seq.length', max(sizes)])
    print(table)
```

Comment: If you can't fit the whole FASTA file in memory you will need to read sequences one at a time. Look at the Bio.SeqIO.FastaIO.FastaIterator class. The problem here is that the iterator will be empty once you've gone through it so you are in some ways back to your original problem - you would have to recreate the FastaIterator each time you wish to use it.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you only ever use the record length and ID from the file. You could just load those into a list of tuples or two separate lists and pass those around. There is certainly no reason to keep parsing your file over and over.

First write a function to load the relevant data. I think a pair of lists is better since you only use the IDs once:

```
def load_file(filename):
    data = [(rec.id, len(rec)) for rec in SeqIO.parse(fasta_file, "fasta")]
    # Transpose the data into two lists instead of list of pairs
    return tuple(map(list, zip(*data)))
```

Now your function calls should look like

```
fasta = 'filename.fa'
ids, sizes = load_file(fasta)
fasta_outlook(sizes)
fasta_lendist(sizes)
fasta_burst(ids, sizes)
```

In `fasta_outlook` and `fasta_lendist`, you just change the input parameter name to `sizes` and remove the comprehension that computes those values. In `fasta_burst`, you can simplify the loop somewhat:

```
def fasta_burst(ids, sizes):
'''Reports the length of each fasta sequence in the file. Takes filename as string'''
    with open("Seq_length.tab","w") as my_file:
        for id, rec in zip(ids, sizes):
            my_file.write('{}\t{}\n'.format(id, size))
    print("Length report written in Seq_length.tab")
```

Use a `with` block do ensure that your file is closed after you're done with it. You weren't closing at all before, and `with` has the advantage of closing even if an error occurs.